# How can I work with this Module/Class setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

I have the following module/class:

```
module Pigeons
  class FedEx

    attr_accessor :signature_name

    def initialize(account)
      self.account = account
    end

    def response(number)
      body = "...some xml..."
      return HTTParty.post('http://example.com', :body => body)
    end

    def track(number)
      details = response(number)

      self.signature_name = details[:delivery_signature_name]      
    end 
  end
end
```

What I'd like to be able to do is this:

```
@fedex ||= Pigeons::FedEx.new('123abc')
tracker = fedex.track('1234567890')
tracker.signature_name
```

Everything is working up until the `tracker.signature_name` part, which throws an `undefined method 'signature_name' for nil:NilClass` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
self.signature_name = details[:delivery_signature_name]
```

`details[:delivery_signature_name]` turns out to be `nil`, which is then assigned to `self.signature_name` and then becomes return value of `track` method. And here

```
tracker = fedex.track('1234567890')
tracker.signature_name
```

`tracker` will be `nil` and you try to call a method on it.

You probably meant to write this instead:

```
def track(number)
  details = response(number)

  self.signature_name = details[:delivery_signature_name]      
  self # <== here
end
```

Comment: Forgot to include that in my sample code (just updated it now), but I actually already have that.

Comment: I'd make it a class method though because you're not returning a true/false or a value but the full object. So make it `def self.track`.

Answer (score 0):

You need two methods called `signature_name=` and `response` that do whatever they are supposed to do in your class.

Comment: I was attempting to keep my sample code in this post as brief and to the point as I could, but I've updated to show that I already have a `response` method and I'm using `attr_accessor` to access `signature_name`